# Mysql vs Postgres Read Operations

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, compare

We are running an application that uses MySql with Engine InnoDB and we are planning to revamp the application (source code), so I was looking at postgres as it seems to be very popular and suggested by many people around the world. But there is something which really has put me on hold:

[Taken from this thread.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems)

> **When Not To Use PostgreSQL**
>
> **Speed**: If all you require is fast read operations, PostgreSQL is not
>   the tool to go for.
>
> **Simple set ups**: Unless you require absolute data integrity, ACID
>   compliance or complex designs, PostgreSQL can be an over-kill for
>   simple set-ups.
>
> **Replication**: Unless you are willing to spend the time, energy and
>   resources, achieving replication with MySQL might be simpler for those
>   who lack the database and system administration experience.

So, about speed, I am not sure what exactly it means by fast read operations. Does it mean simple read operations or complex? Because I also have read that postgres optimizes the query before executing it, so not sure if I truly understand the point or missing something?

In the end, I am not sure, which factors exactly should I look for choosing Postgres or Mysql for the application?

**Note**: I have read and tried to understand the differences between postgres and mysql but couldn't conclude anything, that is why I am posting question here. Also, I am not a DBA.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the application and its data needs?  The blurb you pasted is basically saying that Postgres can be overkill depending on your requirements.

Comment: Too broad, too opinionated. Beware.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's an ECommerce application which will primarily focus on more reading than writing.

Comment: For an ECommerce application, I'd imagine that data integrity is pretty important...

Comment: Please read the very detailed review of Postgres vs MySQL made by Uber. https://eng.uber.com/mysql-migration/. MySQL, implementation wise, is a better product than Postgres. The non-mutuble tuple arhictecture of Postgres is a major bottleneck. One small update sends riple effects to all indexes. The replication design is catastrophe, with too much data shipped to replicas. And the fact that the WAL data is sent to replicas as opposed to logical updates, means that any replica that is getting WAL updates and starts a transaction, may have to block executing WAL updates just because of a READ.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL can compress and decompress its data on the fly with a fast compression scheme to fit more data in an allotted disk space. The advantage of compressed data, besides saving disk space, is that reading data takes less IO, resulting in faster data reads.

Mysql: MyISAM tables suffer from table-level locking, and do not support ACID features such as data durability, crash recovery, transactions or foreign keys. Previously it has been claimed to perform better in read-only or read-heavy operations, but this is no longer necessarily the case.

Also see [Benchmarking PostgreSQL vs. MySQL performance](http://2bits.com/articles/benchmarking-postgresql-vs-mysql-performance-using-drupal-5x.html)

**It is highly depends on how your table structure maintained and how you are organising data.**

[Pinterest though using mysql](https://engineering.pinterest.com/blog/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet/) have managed huge data with faster read.

Comment: who mentioned they wanted to use MyISAM ?

Comment: Just made point about MyISAM. My motive to answer is highlighted.

Comment: Best to vote close as too broad or opinionated imo. Unless you have benchmarks for various engines (not the dumpy one you chose to mention MyISAM), and can speak to WebScaleSql, Tukodb, Percona, fractals, and others. Plus that is just scratching the surface of comparisons

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Thanks for taking time to reply to the broad question as mentioned by Drew and voted to close as well. Not sure, where can one ask such broad questions. Well, coming back to the point, the benchmarking link you have shared, I already have gone through it and looking at that seems like I should really not go with postgres at all. Author seemed to be biased towards mysql (not sure why). I will surely read through pinterest through mysql link. But how is it possible for me to do benchmarking myself? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @ssc: I loved the way Pinterest have scaled to have support for heavy read requests on mysql. There are already many benchmark results are present for both DB's. It is highly dependent on your application structure and how reads are made on tables. You can also go for non relational databases like MongoDb for high read spead. You should make question based on your application and DB structure. Narrow down your question.

Answer (score 0):

All depends upon your application. If you are creating web application and that can be more complex, many tables with joins you are using, real time data. In that case you can prefer Postgresql.

**PostgreSql Features** : ORDBMS, MVCC, It can also be accessed by Routines from the platform native C library as well as Streaming API for large objects, Table inheritance, it is unified database server with a single storage engine, more reliable and fast in complex operation where many joins you are using, Locking to avoid race condition, having a lot of functions like --> To text search to_tsvecter() and to_tsquery(), get data in json format, having shared buffer cache, indexing, triggers, backup, master-slave replication and many more.

If your application is small, mobile platform, similar types of queries you are using, not many users for this application. In that case you can prefer Mysql.

**Mysql Features** :  RDBMS, used JDBC ODBC, fast for similar types of queries, master-master replication.